# core data structure

Tags: ios, core-data

Im about to add the persistence layer to my application, and i decided to give core data a go. Currently i map all my models to entities, which seems to work quite well. But in my current implementation i use something i call "collections" (of models) for example i have a collection of tile slots in a game.

this SlotsCollection class has methods like findNextInSameRow() findAvailableSlot() etc. What ive done with core data is i have created a Game entity and added a to many relationship to the Slot entity, Is there a way to define a class which the collection of slots should be instantiated with so i can put my logic inside that? Or is there a better way for me to structure things. I guess i could create "managers" inside my Game entity and hand in the slots when initialized

```
SlotManager* manager = [SlotManager alloc] initWithSlots:self.slots];
Slot* slot = [manager findAvailableSlot];
```

Also after i "migrated" all my models to entities, i have alot of entities that do not have any attributes but only hold references to other entities. Im abit afraid im using a wrong mindset when structuring the core data.

Answer (score 0):

The class that has the collection should have the logic for that collection.

If you have a 1-to-many relationship from A to B, then you'd put the logic about this relationship into class A — and possibly some of it inside class B (depending on your needs).

Note: If you're iterating through relationships, you need to be aware of faulting behavior etc. Whenever Core Data has to do actual database work, you incur a performance hit. That's no different that plain old SQL. If you don't have to "go to disk" things are very fast. If you're using fetch request you will *always* do database work, and things will always be (relatively) expensive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've been looking for some standard solutions for this but without any luck, im not sure i like the idea of putting all the logic inside the containing entity, in my case this can result in a very heavy entity with alot of responsibilities.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing non-standard stuff. That's why there's no standard solution for it. Perhaps you can elaborate on what exactly you're trying to solve?